# Identify columns by column names not offset in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv

In php, I am reading a CSV file into an array of arrays, i.e. each line on file becomes one array with an array comprising the whole file. I can access a cell in the array by a combination of its row and column number, e.g. arr[36][0], but what is the best way to assign names to the columns? Is it to use a constant, e.g. const COL1 = 0; and refer to arr[36][COL1], or can you use keys in some form?

Comment: If your CSV is written and read by code, constants are usually good enough. If the read/write logic can be in the same codebase it is even better. If humans get involved with the CSV, I wouldn’t assume column order, and instead  scan the first row for expected column names, noting their index in a map. Or just use a [library](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/reader/) that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the first row of your csv file has the column titles, you can use it to create associative arrays for each row with array_combine function (creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values).

```
array_combine(array $keys , array $values) : array
```

You have to read the first row (titles) into $titles array and then for every other row use array_combine (using $titles array) to get and associative array.